# How to use interpolation for the ID attribute in Jade/Pug

Tags: javascript, html, pug, canvasjs

I am trying to dynamically build chartContainers based on a MongoDB Database. For some background, I am using CanvasJS to create stock charts. I have a "stocks" variable I iterate through which is an array of all the elements in my database. This is my first web development project and my first time using javascript and pug so apologies if there is an obvious question. For reference, I built this project using [this template](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Node-Starter)

```
   console.log(stocks);
      for(const element of stocks){
        const str = 'chartContainer' + element.ticker;
        console.log(str);
        // Need to get data for that chart
        renderChart(data1, str, element.ticker);
      }
```

[When this runs here is my log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgPHr.png)

Here is the render chart function(.js file)

```
function renderChart(chartData, chartContainer, Ticker = "Ticker") {
var chart1 = new CanvasJS.Chart(chartContainer,
  {
  title:{
  text: Ticker}, 
  axisY:{ title:"Price",minimum: 0, maximum: 6, includeZero: false},
  data: chartData });

  chart1.render();
  }
```

To make these "charts" show up on the webserver I need to create chart containers with the ID that I have defined earlier. This is in my pug file and it works as expected when I have two items in my database named TSLA and GOOGL.

```
  #chartContainerTSLA(style='width: 25%; height: 300px;display: inline-block;')
  #chartContainerGOOGL(style='width: 25%; height: 300px;display: inline-block;')
```

However, The issue I am having is I want to make the ticker at the end a string that I am changing. I was following [this link](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html) for how to interpolate it but it is not working.

**Some things I have tried:**

```
  for result in stocks
    #chartContainer!{result.ticker}(style='width: 25%; height: 300px;display: inline-block;')
```

I also tried replacing the ! with a # and neither of them worked
Here is the error that is thrown

```
 36|   for result in stocks
 37|     #chartContainer!{result.ticker}(style='width: 25%; height: 300px;display: inline-block;')
 ---------------------------^
 unexpected text "!{res"
```

I also tried

```
 for result in stocks
  - var containerName='chartContainer#{result.ticker}'
  #!{containerName}(style='width: 25%; height: 300px;display: inline-block;')
```

That threw the error

```
 36|     for result in stocks
 37|       - var containerName='chartContainer#{result.ticker}'
 38|       #!{containerName}(style='width: 25%; height: 300px;display: inline-block;')
 --------------^
 "!{containerName}" is not a valid ID.
```

I am looking for a way to generate these chart containers dynamically so I don't have to manually create chart containers every time something is entered into the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called [attribute interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html#attribute-interpolation) in Pug.

In Pug, the shorthand for giving an element an `id` attribute is the **hash syntax** you're already using and familiar with:

```
div#chartContainer
```

However, this can also be written using the **regular attribute syntax**, like so:

```
div(id="chartContainer")
```

In order to use interpolation within the `id` attribute, you must use the regular attribute syntax instead of the shorthand.

This would be how you could use attribute interpolation with the `id` attribute in your loop, using either JS string concatenation or [JS template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
// using string concatenation
for result in stocks
  div(id= 'chartContainer' + result.ticker, style='...')

// using template strings
for result in stocks
  div(id=`chartContainer${result.ticker}`, style='...')
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution

Inside JS script:

```
for(const element of stocks){
        renderChart(data1, element.ticker, element.ticker);
      }
```

Inside Pug:

```
for result in stocks
   div(id=result.ticker,style='width: 25%; height: 300px;display: inline-block;')
```